# problem with import directories for files to be imported

Tags: magento-1.7, import, image, avs-fastsimpleimport

I have a custom made importer, that uses AvS_FastSimpleImport. Anyway, importing the products and every other attribute is fine. The problem comes with importing the images. If I have the directory hierarchy like that:

```
project_name/media/import/(the .xml file of the product + the images files)
```

the images are being imported all fine.
But there's a new requirement the hierarchy to be done the following way:

```
project_name/media/Import/XML/(the .xml file of the product)
project_name/media/Import/Images/(the images files)
```

then the images are not being imported. All other configurations in `config.xml` files and in the back-end are set up correctly, according to the different hierarchy cases, so mis-setting of options is not the problem.

My suspicion is that there is some convention of directory hierarchy which therefore makes the importing not working if the hierarchy is some custom. Is that the case?

Additional info: in the second hierarchy case - there are no folders and files created in the `/media/catalog/product` where the pictures to be imported should be copied, as it should happen as follows `project_name/media/catalog/product/X/Y/XYimagename.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out. Just for whoever will stumble upon similar problem, here's the answer:

Magento core code has a hard-coded line, that searches for images (to be imported) in `...media/import' directory. You can see this line in

```
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Mode/Import/Entity/Product.php    -> line 1405
```

So, if you want the images (that are to be imported) to be taken from another folder, different from `/media/import`, then you'll have to override the upper mentioned model class. :)